# Adobe Illustrator 9 won't open on brand new computer

Tags: windows-8, adobe-illustrator

I have tried many times to install Adobe Illustrator 9 on my brand new Windows 8 computer. It is showing in the installed programs but it won't open.

What do I need to do to make it functional?

Comment: Its windows 8 and it apears to install but cant open it, adobe illustrator 9. Brand new computer with excellent systems

Comment: to you have any error?

Comment: Adobe Illustrator 9 is nearly 10 years old. Its very likely there are compatability problems with Adobe Illustrator 9 and Windows 8. I do not believe Adobe Illustrator 9 would even run on Windows 7. In order to clarify a detail are we talking about Windows 8 x86 or Windows 8 x64.  Be sure you patch Adobe Illustrator 9 to Adobe Illustrator 9.0.1 and run it in Windows XP compatability mode.

Answer (score 5):

Right-click the Illustrator icon and choose Properties.

When the Properties dialog box appears, click the Compatibility tab and then click the Run Compatibility Troubleshooter button.

Windows 8 will then try to guess what version of Windows your program needs, and then it applies the changes.

If it still doesn't work select the Run This Program in Compatibility Mode For check box and select the program's desired Windows version from the drop-down list (I'd recommend Windows XP SP3).

Comment: Worked like a charm to get Illustrator 10 going on windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Illustrator (CC) is effectively version 17 - you're likely to have trouble getting version 9 working on a modern machine. [Illustrator 9 was released in 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator#Release_history) for Windows 98.

A **decent Illustrator alternative that is free and open source** is **[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)**. It's improving fast (e.g. it's finally starting to get good CMYK support, though some workarounds are still needed), it's better than it looks, and while it's not as good as Illustrator 14+ (CS4+), I'd choose it over version 9. Adapting to Inkscape is probably easier than trying to make Windows 98 software run on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I run illustrator 9.01 on windows 7 home edition mini tablet. SOrt of works. Best to keep a single tower XP machine with sp3, and run all old adobe progs and office 97. Goes at rocket speed and files are nice and small. Also not on net so virus free. Then get a laptop win 8 for browsing.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the task manager and find the 32-bit setup process that is created when you try to launch the installer.  If you tried and failed a few times, then there may be many of these listed.  Kill all but one of the processes.  Then go to the details pane (available in win10, not sure about earlier versions).  Find the process in the details pane, then right click on the process.  Select the option "analyze wait chain".  If you see that the process is waiting for something else to terminate, that is where the hangup is...

In my case the g0dd@mn Skype install process (which I think always loads at boot-up - why?) was blocking the Adobe installer!!!  Yes, it was as simple as that.

I closed Skype and - poof - it worked!

I haven't been able to get this app working since win7, but I think that this simple problem might have been the only reason why.  Silly.

I hope that this works for you.

Cheers

Comment: Oh, and BTW,  don't forget to disable display scaling for the installed application on high DPI displays if the fonts look crappy in win8 or win10...  (under properties in the file explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Same here, Adobe Illustrator wouldn't open in Windows 8.1. At first I managed to open it via [right-click app > Troubleshoot compatibility> continue troubleshooting the program >try recommended settings > test the program] but that's a hassle. Thanks to the tips here I found another way to open it 'normally'. (I had nothing holding up the above mentioned "wait chain").

Open task manager, then open Illustrator, it will close immediately but it should leave a window stating it shut down. Don't close that window yet or illustrator will disappear from task manager. In your task manager: right-click adobe illustrator> properties>compatibility>tick 'run this program in compatibility mode for: I choose windows 8. So far so good, it's opening and operating normally.